# How to change Icon according to user actions?

Tags: react-native

I am developing a project with react native. I have a header with a Text and an Icon.

```
const Header = ({ navigation, state }) => (

    <View style={styles.header}>

        <View style={styles.identidadeAppContainer}>
            <View style={styles.nomeAppContainer}><Text style={styles.nomeAppText}>BigodeAPP</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.logoAppContainer}><Image style={styles.imageLogo} source={Images.logoBigodeApp}></Image></View>

        </View>
        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
            {
                !state ? 
                <Icon name="angle-down" size={25} color={colors.secundary} />
                :
                <Icon name="cut" size={25} color={colors.secundary} />

            }

        </View>

    </View>

)
```

I call the Header inside my APP:

```
<Header state={stateMenu} />
```

stateMenu is a boolean variable which changes according to the user's actions.

However, even with stateMenu changing value, I am not able to re-embed the header to make the Icon later.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do by using this way:

```
const Header = ({ navigation, state }) => (

    <View style={styles.header}>

        <View style={styles.identidadeAppContainer}>
            <View style={styles.nomeAppContainer}><Text style={styles.nomeAppText}>BigodeAPP</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.logoAppContainer}><Image style={styles.imageLogo} source={Images.logoBigodeApp}></Image></View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
            <Icon name={state ? "cut" : "angle-down"} size={25} color={colors.secundary} />
        </View>
    </View>
)
```

Theres a `one line if statement` on the `name` prop

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do this way ... but even so, the Icons do not change with the status, they are fixed.

Comment: maybe you need to cause a re-render when you want to change the icon. This can be done by using `this.setState` or `this.forceUpdate()`